# File getting corrupted when sending in a PUT request via Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a file that I am trying to send from one server to another. Since a `File` object represents a specific location on the file system, and that file won't exist on the new server when I send it, I have to transfer it over some other way.

I figured the best way to send it would be a simple byte array, like so (making use of Apache Commons [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)):

```
File file = <...>;
byte[] fileByteArray = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
restTemplate.put("http://example.com/upload/", fileByteArray);
```

I then receive the file on the other end like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void upload(
        @NotNull @RequestBody byte[] data
) {
    File file = <...>;
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, data);
}
```

However, the file on the other end is corrupted. For instance, if I send a zip file over and try to open it up in Windows Explorer, I am told that it is invalid, even though it worked perfectly fine on the other end. What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with sending across the file as a `byte[]`. Spring is converting it to a `String`, then turning that `String` into a `byte[]` (equivalent to `String.getBytes()`). This produces a slightly different `byte[]` than what you started with, which is causing the corruption.

Instead, you should either send across an `InputStream` or, if you must send across a `byte[]`, send it in a wrapped object.